# Subfiles project issue: cannot load more than a single subfile

Tags: subfiles

I tried to use the instructions from [this link](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Multi-file_LaTeX_projects#The_standalone_package) to split my current master thesis into multiple .tex files using the subfiles package.

However, I am unable to compile more than a single file. I have reproduced a minimalist version of the code to highlight the issue.

```
%test_main.tex:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel} 
\usepackage{expl3}
\usepackage{subfiles}                                               

\begin{document}
    \subfile{test1}
    \subfile{test2}
\end{document}

%test1.tex
\documentclass[test_main.tex]{subfiles}
\begin{document}
    This is the first document.
\end{document}

%test2.tex
\documentclass[test_main.tex]{subfiles}
\begin{document}
    This is the second document.
\end{document}
```

All three documents (test_main.tex, test1.tex, test2.tex) are located in a single folder. I can compile text_main.tex without receiving a single error message or warning, however the resulting .pdf contains only "This is the first document.".

Does anybody have a clue of what is going on?

Comment: What happen if you comment out the line `\subfile{test 1}` ? And what is the result of compiling `test2.tex` alone?

Comment: If I comment out \subfile{test1} then I obtain a document with "This is the second document." as expected. Also, I am able to compile test2.tex alone, which yields the same result. Also, if I permute the lines \subfile{test1} and \subfile{test2}, then I also obtain the same result. 

So it only compiles the first subfile and ignore the second. Actually, it ignores everything past the first \subfile{...} command.

Comment: I have no issues when compiling your example in overleaf! Does the code you provide reproduce the problem you are describing?Which latex distribution do you use?

Comment: Yes. I tried this exact code to make sure the problem was persistent (and it is).

I am not exactly sure of my technical specs (as I set up my LaTeX environment quite a while ago), but I am working with TeXworks and MiKTeX.

Comment: Can you please re-edit your question by adding the content of the file `test_main.log` located in the same directory.

Answer (score 0):

Use `\subfile{test1.tex}` instead of `\subfile{test1}`.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Have you tried it? Result?